# How to modify small parts of json string without parsing the whole string?

Tags: c#, json, string, json.net

I'm trying to modify some data model we stored in json string. Typically I would want to change some property values on some of the nodes in the whole object tree. So far I could use JObject.Parse() to parse the whole string, and then change the bits and serialise back to json string.

The problem is when the json string is big and a single object with lots of children objects, the memory usage of JObject.Parse() could be even bigger. Is there any efficient way to only parse object without its children, and potentially save the changes back into the json string?

Some example json:

```
{
    "type": "fooType",
    "id": "foo0",           //need change the id from "foo0" to "foo1"
    "children": [{
        "type": "barType",  //need change the type from "barType" to "otherType"
        "id": "bar0",
        "children": [...]
    },{
        "type": "barType",
        "id": "bar1",       //need change the type from "barType" to "otherType"
        "children": [...]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code / json?  In theory you can read it as a regular string and perform some regex replaces, then save it back.  But it really depends on your data.

Comment: I have updated with some example json string. regex probably will do, but the level of children hierarchy could be very deep.

Comment: Did you tried deserialize - change - serialize json? How more memory it takes. Did you tried it with regex - how more memory regex takes for this process.